# In Flutter's TextPainter text color differs in debug and release

Tags: flutter, dart

In this Flutter project while running in the emulator and the test device the text color in 
 shown in **black** but after converting the project in to an apk file then text is shown in **white** color. I do not understand what is wrong with the `TextPainter` ?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:project/game_controller.dart';

class HighscoreText {
  final GameController gameController;
  TextPainter painter;
  Offset position;

  HighscoreText(this.gameController) {
    painter = TextPainter(
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    );
    position = Offset.zero;
  }

  void render(Canvas c) {
    painter.paint(c, position);
  }

  void update(double t) {
    int highscore = gameController.storage.getInt('HighScore') ?? 0;
    painter.text = TextSpan(
      text: 'Highscore: $highscore',
      style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black, fontSize: 35.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
    );
    painter.layout();
    position = Offset(
        (gameController.screenSize.width / 2) - (painter.width / 2),
        (gameController.screenSize.height * 0.2) - (painter.height / 2));
  }
}
```

Comment: do you use flame-engine https://github.com/flame-engine/flame ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to reproduce the issue while using [flame-engine](https://github.com/flame-engine/flame) but when I use CustomPainter with TextPainter to paint your text, the text color keeps in Black in both debug and release modes so I'd suggest opening an issue on [flame-engine](https://github.com/flame-engine/flame/issues)

Here is a working version of your snippet uses CustomPainter and TextPainter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: CustomPaint(
          painter: MyPainter(),
          size: Size.infinite,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final HighscoreText highscoreText = HighscoreText();

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    render(canvas, size);
  }

  void render(Canvas c, Size size) {
    Rect background = Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    Paint backgroundPaint = Paint()..color = Color(0xFF8BC34A);
    c.drawRect(background, backgroundPaint);

    highscoreText.render(c, size);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}

class HighscoreText {
  TextPainter painter;

  HighscoreText() {
    painter = TextPainter(
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    );

    painter.text = TextSpan(
      text: 'Highscore: 1234',
      style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black, fontSize: 35.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
    );
    painter.layout();
  }

  void render(Canvas c, Size size) {
    Offset position = Offset((size.width / 2) - (painter.width / 2),
        (size.height * 0.2) - (painter.height / 2));
    painter.paint(c, position);
  }
}
```